# PHP preg_match_all behave strange

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I am using a regular expression search. But the search is not working with php preg_match_all method. But when I am using the same pattern at [regex101](https://www.regex101.com/) and it's perfectly working there. So any clue what I am missing. The code and subject is as below

```
preg_match_all($patern, $str, $match,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

//++ the pattern
~\](.*?)\[\d~

//The str or subject

[07-Jul-2016 04:33:15] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/ssh2.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/ssh2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0 [07-Jul-2016 04:34:17] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/ssh2.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/ssh2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0 [07-Jul-2016 05:14:01] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/ssh2.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/ssh2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0 [08-Jul-2016 23:27:23] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/ssh2.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/ssh2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0 [10-Jul-2016 03:14:02] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/ssh2.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/ssh2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0 [17-Jul-2016 03:42:01] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/ssh2.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/ssh2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0 [24-Jul-2016 03:33:01] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/ssh2.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/ssh2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0 [31-Jul-2016 03:28:01] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/ssh2.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/ssh2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0 [07-Aug-2016 04:24:02] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/ssh2.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/ssh2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0 [11-A
```

And the output of the match are as below

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(0) { } [1]=> array(0) { } }
```

Basically I want to capture all warning or error messages,
But the main concern is that the pattern is working on regex101.com but not in my code

Comment: Works fine for me. Show us the code you are using.

Comment: And what exactly is not working?

Comment: There is no issue with preg_match_all , I found there are some other errors showing in your description, just check them to fix.

Comment: Most probably you need to use `~\](.*?)\[\d~s`: `preg_match_all('~\](.*?)\[\d~s', $str, $match,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, it's working now. My Bad. Can you please post an answer with an explanation. So I can choose that as right one